# Attach to a processes output for viewing

Tags: linux, logging, command-line-interface

How would I 'attach' a console/terminal-view to an applications output so I can see what it may be saying?

How would I detach from an applications output without killing the application?

Normally if you fire up a talkative application using the command line you get to see all kinds of wonderful output. However, let’s say I have a particularly chatty programming running, like KINO, and I want to view its output at any given moment without restarting it through the command line. I cannot; at least I don't know how.

Comment: Do you have debug symbol in your process? Does it run in production environnement? And if so do you need it to NEVER been paused ?

Comment: When I have bouts of stability issues with end user programs like kino (crashes and kills my sound) I want to be able to know how/why it crashed so I can work on fixing it. This isn't a program I'm developing but a technique I'd like to know for trouble shooting. I'll try your suggestion below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a few options here.  One is to redirect the output of the command to a file, and then use 'tail' to view new lines that are added to that file in real time.

Another option is to launch your program inside of 'screen', which is a sort-of text-based Terminal application.  Screen sessions can be attached and detached, but are nominally meant only to be used by the same user, so if you want to share them between users, it's a big pain in the ass.

Comment: "There are a few options here. One is to redirect the output of the command to a file, and then use 'tail' to view new lines that are added to that file in real time." 

Can this be done with already running applications?

Comment: You probably need tail -f $log_file to get the output as it is written in the file.

Also, no, there is no way I know of to do that with an already running app.

Comment: @aggitan: No.  For existing applications, you'll have to restart them, because they've already bound their I/O to the controlling terminal.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process

Answer (score 393):

I think I have a simpler solution here. Just look for a directory whose name corresponds to the PID you are looking for, under the pseudo-filesystem accessible under the `/proc` path. So if you have a program running, whose ID is 1199, `cd` into it:

```
$ cd /proc/1199
```

Then look for the `fd` directory underneath

```
$ cd fd
```

This `fd` directory hold the file-descriptors objects that your program is using (0: stdin, 1: stdout, 2: stderr) and just `tail -f` the one you need - in this case, stdout):

```
$ tail -f 1
```

Comment: I was unable to use `tail` as in my case the output was redirected to another process for input, but `more` showed me the current data.

Comment: @Ωmega - Wouldn't you be able to find the process that you're redirecting it into, and then tail it's stdin (/proc/#/0)?

Comment: In my environment actually `tail` didn't work at any scenario, only `head` and `more`...

Comment: One of the most riveting posts on this site!

Comment: `more` is working for me. ubuntu 14.04 on a node process

Comment: This is not working for me with a java process which calls System.out.println.  There is no output at all to /proc/[pid]/fd/1

Comment: @Nick I don't know about Java but you might need to check JRE pid (or something like that). I won't be impressed if Java is heavily buffering stdout either.

Comment: Tried to create a reproduction using the below, but to no avail:

```
docker run -it --name container1 ubuntu bash -c -i "COUNT=0; while true; do echo Keep the dance floor beat going; ((COUNT++)); sleep 1; echo \"Count is: \${COUNT}\"; done;"
```

In another terminal:

```
docker exec -it container1 tail -f /proc/1/fd/1
```

Comment: Sorry @JacobWuzHere. I don't have Docker experience, I'm not sure if Docker even uses the `proc` filesystem :(

Comment: Best discovery this year! This feature rocks!

Comment: Wow this is so interesting. what happens for me is that doing a tail on a stdout of one process in python affects the input of another processes in python. for example keystrokes in a debug session of python are getting skipped. Very interesting.

Comment: This will work if process has already allocated tty. You can check if tty is allocated or not using `ps' command. If it shows `?` in TTY column then no tty allocated, then there is nothing to check in /proc/PID/fd.

Comment: @TejasSarade hm... my processes (running from bare Konsole or Tmux on Kubuntu 18.04) report that they have a TTY, but I can't tail or less the file descriptors anyway. At least, there seems to be nothing in them.

Comment: For me, `tail` worked after I changed my current user to the owner of the process with `su proc_owner`. Even as `root` I was denied access.

Comment: For me, ls lists 1 in red, and Midnight Commander reports @1 -> /dev/pts/1 (deleted).

Answer (score 69):

I was looking for this exact same thing and found that you can do:

```
strace -ewrite -p $PID
```

It's not exactly what you needed, but it's quite close.

I tried the redirecting output, but that didn't work for me.
Maybe because the process was writing to a socket, I don't know.

Comment: thanks it works, but output is truncated, e.g. for ping:
write(1, "64 bytes from 1.0.0.1: icmp_seq="..., 56) = 56

Comment: @izy you can specify a `-sLENGTH` flag to set a new buffersize (default 32). for more details, check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58601

Answer (score 15):

For me, this worked:

1. Login as the owner of the process (even `root` is denied permission)

   ```
   ~$ su - process_owner
   ```
2. Tail the file descriptor as mentioned in many other answers.

   ```
   ~$ tail -f /proc/<process-id>/fd/1 # (0: stdin, 1: stdout, 2: stderr)
   ```

Comment: What if file descriptors point to a socket? `# ls -la /proc/24510/fd/1 lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Oct 31 08:34 /proc/24510/fd/1 -> socket:[444026]`

Answer (score 15):

You can use `reptyr`:

```sh
sudo apt install reptyr
reptyr pid
```

Comment: if `reptyr $PID` did not work try `sudo reptyr -T $PID` based on this [issue](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr/issues/62#issuecomment-138653405)

Answer (score 8):

> How would I 'attach' a
>   console/terminal-view to an
>   applications output so I can see what
>   it may be saying?

About this question, I know it is possible to catch the output, even when you didn't launch sceen command before launching the processus.

While I never tried it, I've found an interesting article which explains how to do using GDB (and without restarting your process).

[redirecting-output-from-a-running-process](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/)

Basically:

1. Check the open files list for your process, thanks to **/proc/xxx/fd**
2. **Attach** your process with GDB
3. While it is paused, close the file you are interested in, calling **close()** function (you can any function of your process in GDB. I suspect you need debug symbols in your process..)
4. Open the a new file calling the **create()** or open() function. (Have a look in comments at  the end, you'll see people suggest to use **dup2()** to ensure the same handle will be in use)
5. **Detach** the process and let in run.

By the way, if you are running a linux OS on i386 box, comments are talking about a better  tool to redirect output to a new console : ***'retty'*** . If so, consider its use.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to remotely watch a yum upgrade process that had been run locally, so while there were probably more efficient ways to do this, here's what I did:

```
watch cat /dev/vcsa1
```

Obviously you'd want to use vcsa2, vcsa3, etc., depending on which terminal was being used.

So long as my terminal window was of the same width as the terminal that the command was being run on, I could see a snapshot of their current output every two seconds. The other commands recommended elsewhere did not work particularly well for my situation, but that one did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler option is `cat`:

`cat /proc/<pid>/fd/1`

Especially if `tail` does not work for you due to permission errors (even using `sudo`), or if the process to monitor display a progress bar using curses or an equivalent library.