# Python on system start up

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running Python on a Raspberry Pi and everything works great.
I have a small script running on the system start up which prints several warning messages (which I actually cannot read since it is running in the background)...

My question is: Is there a way via SSH to "open" this running script instance and see what is going on or a log file is the only way to work with that?

Thanks!

Comment: you can write the warning message to file then read it later

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking, what exactly are you trying to read?

Comment: a script does not change so I cannot see how looking inside it will do much

Comment: The messages depend on sensors installed to the Raspberry Pi. So the script does not change but the messages do. :)

Comment: then you want the output from running the script not to access the script. Have you tried outputting the data as the script runs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach to a processes output for viewing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715751/attach-to-a-processes-output-for-viewing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Python `logging` library.  You can configure it to save the output to a file and then you can use `tail -f mylogfile.log` to watch as content is put in.

**EDIT:**

An alternative is to use `screen`.  It allows you to run a command in a virtual console, detach from that console, and then disconnect from the machine.  You can then reconnect to the machine and re-attach to that console and see all the output the process made.  I'm not sure about using it on a script that starts when the machine is turned on, though (I simply haven't tried it).

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your python script to write its output to a file instead of to the screen (which you can't see). I.e., I think that a log file is your best (possibly only) bet. You can write to a file in /tmp on the raspberry pi if you just want a temporary log file that you can check once and a while.
Also, as Tim said, you could try out the python logging library, but I think just writing to a file is quicker and easier, although you might run into some issues with permissions...