# Is it possible to read messages passed over stdout from within a Docker container? (without `docker logs`)

Tags: logging, docker, lxc

**Motivation:** To run a basic health-check on a docker container by counting that a certain number of messages flow across stdout over a certain time horizon

**Immediate goal:** From within a shell started by `docker exec`, read data that is being piped to stdout from the main process (PID 1)

I am not even sure if what I want is possible. If that is the case, an explanation as to why not would be much appreciated -- and would help advance my knowledge.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start the container -- `container1`

   `docker run -it --name container1 ubuntu bash -c -i "COUNT=0; while true; do echo Keep the dance floor beat going; ((COUNT++)); sleep 1; echo \"Count is: \${COUNT}\"; done;"`
2. In another terminal window, `docker exec` to start another process in the same container

   `docker exec -it container1 bash`

Can I somehow `tail`/`print`/`read` the messages being passed over stdout by PID 1?

I understand that there are work arounds -- for example piping through `tee` or otherwise writing to disk -- but was hoping for a magic bullet.

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17790708/2079781

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was not able to get that solution to work with the replication I provided above.

Comment: I did not find a quick solution, but you may have a look at https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout which grabs the log output of a container "somehow" and usually pipes it to a remote collector. (edit: hmm, I think this also works via the Docker-host, so it might not be what you're looking for)

Comment: Why isn't `tee` a valid magic bullet? Is an unmodified entrypoint a requirement of a valid solution for you? Does it need to work inside the container without any additional capabilities added? If so, you may be looking for unobtanium.

Answer (score 4):

If you are OK with `strace` then try this:

```
docker exec -it container1 bash -c -i "\
    apt-get update && apt-get install strace && \
    strace -ff -e trace=write -e write=1 -p 1"
```

- `-p 1` is the PID
- `-e write=1` is there to narrow the output to STDOUT (`-e write=1,2` would show both STDOUT and STDERR)

Depending on Docker version you might need to loosen up Docker's syscall security policy, e.g. by disabling it completely by adding `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined` to `docker run` when starting the container:

```
docker run --security-opt seccomp:unconfined -it --name container1 ubuntu bash -c -i "COUNT=0; while true; do echo Keep the dance floor beat going; ((COUNT++)); sleep 5; ech o \"Count is: \${COUNT}\"; done;"
```

Read more about the Docker's seccomp profiles [here](https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/docker-engine-1-10-security/) (>1.10).

Tested with:

- Windows 8.1
- Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
- Docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87