# Bash: how to listen the output of another running program

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have two bash scripts (`p1.sh` and `p2.sh`), representing two programs:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"
sleep 10s
echo "good morning"
sleep 10s
echo "goodbye !!"
```

And `p2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# listen to the output of p1's program
# if p1 gives "goodbye !!" output, echo "p1 said goodbye!"
```

The workflow is:

1. Run `p1.sh`
2. Get the pid of the `p1` program
3. Let `p2.sh` listen to the `p1` process's output (instead of calling `p1.sh` inside of `p2.sh`), and judge `p1`'s output.

How to realize it? Thanks!

Comment: You could execute p1 as `p1.sh|tee p1.out'  and then use `tail -f p1.out` to monitor the output. This assumes that you mean by output to monitor _standard output_, and not _standard error_.

Comment: There are some weird and wonderful ideas here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/715751/2836621

Answer (score 1):

You can include either of the below lines in p2.sh. These command will exit to the next line only when the desired outcome in p1.sh is reached.

1. If your intent is to check the content of the log, please try below

   ```
   tail -f <p1_log> |grep -m1 'goodbye'
   ```

   This command will exit when p1_log displays goodbye.
   This needs p2.sh started before p1.sh because p2.sh follows/watches p1.sh's log.
2. If your intent to check if p1.sh has completed in p2.sh, you can use the `tail` command as below

   ```
   tail --pid=<p1_pid> -f <p1_log>
   ```

   This command will exit when p1 ends.

Happy to be corrected and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of `p1.sh` to a `while read` loop.

```
p1.sh | while read -r line; do
    if [ "$line" = "goodby !!" ]
    then echo "p1 said goodbye"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! But sorry I didn't make my question clear -- could it be listening to a process (a running program), instead of calling `p1.sh` inside `p2.sh`? Thanks!

Comment: No, there's no way to attach to the output of an existing process.